React component don't recognized window.Telgram.WebApp.initDataUnsafe
I am a beginner
I want to create a telegram mini app .
According to the  telegram API documentation I put  follow link  into  head of index.html of React Project
    <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>

But  in app.js component  when I use console.log(window.Telgram.WebApp.initDataUnsafe);,I get following error in the inspector of telegram beta inspector :
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'WebApp')
    at s (main.4187b710.js:2:143197)
    at vo (main.4187b710.js:2:60543)
    at xi (main.4187b710.js:2:120194)
    at bs (main.4187b710.js:2:109300)
    at gs (main.4187b710.js:2:109228)
    at vs (main.4187b710.js:2:109091)
    at as (main.4187b710.js:2:105871)
    at ls (main.4187b710.js:2:104422)
    at S (main.4187b710.js:2:138324)
    at MessagePort.T (main.4187b710.js:2:138858) fu @   main.4187b710.js:2 main.4187b710.js:2   Uncaught  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'WebApp')
    at s (main.4187b710.js:2:143197)
    at vo (main.4187b710.js:2:60543)
    at xi (main.4187b710.js:2:120194)
    at bs (main.4187b710.js:2:109300)
    at gs (main.4187b710.js:2:109228)
    at vs (main.4187b710.js:2:109091)
    at as (main.4187b710.js:2:105871)

please help me
React component recognize window.telegram.window.Telgram.WebApp
